# Search script does not return queries

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and I'm running into some problems making a simple search engine. The script below doesn't return any queries.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database");

if(isset($_GET['search'])){
$get_value = $_GET['user_query'];

$result_query = "SELECT * FROM data1 WHERE Name LIKE '%$get_value%'";

$run__result = mysql_query($result_query);

while($row_result=mysql_fetch_array($run_result)){

    $Name=$row_result['Name'];
    $Address=$row_result['Address'];
    $City=$row_result['City'];
    $State=$row_result['State'];
    $ZIP=$row_result['ZIP'];
    $Country=$row_result['Country'];
    $Phone=$row_result['Phone'];
    $Website=$row_result['Website'];
    $Category_1=$row_result['Category_1'];
    $Category_2=$row_result['Category_2'];

echo "<div class='results'>

    <h2>$Name</h2>
    <p align='justify'>$Address</p>
    <p align='justify'>$City</p>
    <p align='justify'>$Address</p>
    <p align='justify'>$State</p>
    <p align='justify'>$ZIP</p>
    <p align='justify'>$Country</p>
    <p align='justify'>$Phone</p>
    <p align='justify'>$Website</p>
    <p align='justify'>$Category_1</p>
    <p align='justify'>$Category_2</p>

</div>";

}
}

?>
```

What could be the problem here? All the database fields are correct.

Comment: Your have `$run__result` and `$run_result`. They are not the same. And try to get into PDO. This query you're doing with mysql is basically obsolete.

Comment: First `echo $result_query; die;` after assign `$result_query`, and check whether your query is as you want or not, and let me know.

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. The [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and it was completely removed from PHP 7. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running your while-loop against $run_result

```
while($row_result=mysql_fetch_array($run_result)){
```

You query variable is $run__result.

Change this part ( assignment operator )...

```
$run__result = mysql_query($result_query);
```

Should be:( comparison operator )

```
$run_result == mysql_query($result_query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable name is different `$run__result`

[image]

Comment: I see the typo also, but you should be more explicit in your answer. A beginner will miss your implication.